# Listbox selection handler in GWT

Tags: gwt, listbox

I have a listbox it contains only on item, i.e.:

```
ListBox box = new ListBox();
box.addItem("XXXXX");
```

When I select an item from box, the selected item should displayed in a `TextBox`. If the box contains more than one item it is working, but if it's only one item, the selected item isn't displayed. Even when there is more than one item, I could not select the first item.

Comment: Please post the handler code you're using.

Comment: box.addChangeHandler(new ChangeHandler() {

                            @Override
                            public void onChange(ChangeEvent event) {
                                textBox.setText(box.getItemText(box.getSelectedIndex()));
                            }
                        });

Comment: Please add the code to your question. It's unreadable in the comments.

Comment: what do you mean by "only one item" ....if there is only item in listbox then what is the mean of addChangeHandler() ..how ill it works ...?

Comment: if there is one item in listbox then set it by default in textbox.

Comment: As @nitinverma said, the only one existing item is selected by default so there is no `change` to be fired.

Comment: I have one TextBox next to one ListBox. in the list box the items are loading dynamically.  For example                                                     for(String s:myArray) {                                                          listbox.addItem(s)                                                                                           }. some times more than one item or some times only one item. in first case suppose listBox contains 3 items, the first item "XX", second item "YY" third item "ZZ". now I want to set the selectedItem into textbox.

Comment: @RamananNathamuni Please post a minimal example that shows your issue. Ideally an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

If you have items (options) loaded dynamically, as you have noted in your comment, you surly have a method that puts new values into your `ListBox`. Now you have two ways of copying the initial value into the `TextBox`.

First is to manually copy the selected (first) value to the `TextBox` just after filling up the `ListBox`.

Second is to force firing the `ChangeEvent` just after filling up the `ListBox`:

```
DomEvent.fireNativeEvent(Document.get().createChangeEvent(), box);
```

The second method is more elegant as you already have the `ChangeEvent` listener set up to handle further selection changes.